Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0 for basic CosmosDb insert
My object model:
public class PhoneBook
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

my Container creation:
db.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync("phoneBooks", "/id")

my insert command:
PhoneBook pb = new() { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "hello world };

db.GetContainer("phoneBooks").CreateItemAsync(pb, new PartitionKey(pb.Id));

any idea where I'm going wrong?
I also tried using  "/Id" as partition key because I figured it must be case sensitive. However, no joy. Using the data explorer, I can add content just fine, even if I name the property "id" and the partition key is "/Id". This is an item I manually added

{
"id": "4faebd8b-717a-4692-ae00-74aa209d706f",
"name": "hello world" }


Try adding [JsonProperty("id")] to your Id property (each document has id, not Id)


Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0

Thanks for your suggestion, David. It works well and data got inserted successfully into the Azure Cosmos DB Container by mentioning [JsonProperty("id")] at the Id property, as you can see in the below code.
public class PhoneBook
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public CosmosDbService(string endpointUri, string primaryKey, string databaseId, string containerId)
{
    CosmosClientOptions clientOptions = new CosmosClientOptions
    {
        ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
        MaxRetryAttemptsOnRateLimitedRequests = 5,
        MaxRetryWaitTimeOnRateLimitedRequests = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
    };

    _cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(endpointUri, primaryKey, clientOptions);

    _database = _cosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseId).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Database;

    _container = _database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerId, "/id").GetAwaiter().GetResult().Container;
}

public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string endpointUri = "*****";
    string primaryKey = "*****";
    string databaseId = "db1";
    string containerId = "phoneBooks";

    CosmosDbService cosmosDbService = new CosmosDbService(endpointUri, primaryKey, databaseId, containerId);

    PhoneBook pb = new PhoneBook
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        Name = "hello world",
        Description = "Sample description"
    };

    await cosmosDbService.CreatePhoneBookItemAsync(pb);
}

Output:
{
    "id": "69daea1c-fd73-4c27-89b0-50428f27ef89",
    "Name": "hello world",
    "Description": "Sample description"
}



Go through this link for more information on the error.


Funny thing is - you can add a document with Id, instead if id using the data explorer just fine. The resulting document will have both Id and id properties. And the error had no information whatsoever about a missing id property - imho that would've been useful here.

another way to handle the propblem would be to set the PropertyNamingPolicy of CosmosClientOptions.SerializerOptions to CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.CamelCase
